# How to send automated emails to customers using Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

Please how do I send automated emails to customers using Process Builder? I have set up the criteria and action. My problem is the right recipient type to select while setting email alerts. This automation is for a custom object Bill that does not have the customer email. However, Bill is related to the custom Customer object that has the email field.

I have the recipient type set to users but I want it set to customers when a Bill is created for them.

I saw a solution online that suggested using Email Field as the recipient type. Then added it as the selected option but when I do that none shows as the option. Therefore I can't select it.

Comment: You need a field of Type = Email on `Bill__c` for it to be selectable in the Email Alert definition. More likely than not, this will mean you'll need to use other automation to sync the field from the `Customer__c`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem has been solved using a record flow trigger.